# VBA for Access, run-time error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have one of my object's private variable which is an array: o_exception, declared as:

```
Private o_exception() as string
```

I can fully test it when initialising its values: lower bound, upper bound, values, everything is ok.

I am trying then to define a let property to be able to access the values of the array from outside the object:

```
Property Get exception()
On Error GoTo ERREUR
exception = o_exception
On Error GoTo 0
End Property
```

I am still fully able to identify my property as an array:

```
lbound(myObject.exception) is available
ubound(myObject.exception) is available
isArray(myObject.exception) returns a yes
```

But

```
myObject.exception(0)
```

gives me the following error:

```
run-time error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object
```

I don't have a let, as I don't need it, and I have very similar code running with the very same structure on other objects. My only clue now is that, as myObject is defined as a member of another object (a collection), I must access it by typing:

```
myCollection.myObject.exception(0)
```

By the way, replacing the Property Get by a Public Function gives the very same error ...

Answer (score 3):

A couple of remarks:

- Can't replicate your issue with the information you gave, accessing the array returned by the `Property Get` should work (code below works fine).
  However, the error message is suggesting that the interpreter is considering your code as an assignment, so context may be important, there must be something that is missing from your question.
- Arrays may not behave as you wish, since [they are copied on assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157009%28prot.20%29.aspx), so every time you refer to the `myObject.exception` property, a copy of the internal `o_exception` array is returned.
  You can actually see that by trying to change the content of the array and realizing that it doesn't actually change at all:

```vb
'---------------------------------
' Class1 code '
'---------------------------------
Private o_exception() As String

Property Get exception()
    exception = o_exception
End Property

Private Sub class_initialize()
    ReDim Preserve o_exception(10)
    o_exception(0) = "qwerty"
    o_exception(1) = "azerty"
End Sub    

'---------------------------------
' Test module '
'---------------------------------
Public Sub test()
    Dim a As Class1
    Set a = New Class1

    Debug.Print TypeName(a.exception)

    Debug.Print LBound(a.exception)
    Debug.Print UBound(a.exception)
    Debug.Print IsArray(a.exception)

    Debug.Print a.exception(0)
    a.exception(0) = "asdfg"
    Debug.Print a.exception(0)

    Dim s() As String
    s = a.exception()

    ' Print the memory address of the first string in each array '
    ' We could expect it to be the same, but they are not '
    Debug.Print StrPtr(s(0))
    Debug.Print StrPtr(a.exception(0))

    ' just to prove the point '
    s(0) = "ZZZZZZZZ"
    Debug.Print s(0)
    Debug.Print a.exception(0)

End Sub
```

Calling `test` will print this:

```
Class1
String()
0
10
True
qwerty
qwerty    => Should be 123456!
296094084 
296093004 => Expected to be the same address  as above, it's not!
ZZZZZZZZ
qwerty    => Should be ZZZZZZZZ!
```

To solve that issue, you could use `Collection` or construct your class to return individual objects instead of exposing the array itself, like:

```vb
' Just use myObject.exception(0) as one would expect '
Property Get exception(index As Long) As String
    exception = o_exception(index)
End Property
```

---

Just in passing, since your code looks like you're dealing with error management, I can heartily recommend you have a look at [vbWatchdog](http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.htm). It's really, really great for managing errors in Access in a global way (not affiliated with that product, just a happy user of it).